# Интерфейс слайдера для управления диапазонами букв в русском алфавите

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, плагин, интерфейс

Есть такая подзадача, разработать JavaScript-интерфейс, позволяющий делить по диапазонам букв весь русский алфавит.
Выглядеть это может примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. в интерфейсе мы имеем возможность делить алфавит букв от А до Я на части любого размера.

Данные из этого интерфейса будут сохранятся в виде частей алфавита:
1) А-Г
2) Д-З
3) И-О
4) П-Я

Кнопка Добавить диапазон будет добавлять новый диапазон (новую часть) на слайдер.

В jQuery UI есть стандартный слайдер: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range, но там всего два ползунка, мне же надо сделать так чтобы ползунки (ограничители частей диапазонов) можно было добавлять в процессе работы с интерфейсом.

Сохранять и обрабатывать всё это я буду в PHP, потому конечно же интересно еще как потом получить эти диапазоны в виде массивов в POST например.

Понимаю что такого готового решения наверняка не найти, но всё же может кто-нибудь что-нибудь из готового посоветует наиболее близкое к моей задаче?

Comment: Попробуйте http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/#samples на странице ниже есть пример с мульти слайдером.

Comment: Вот на [этот вариант](http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/#styling-alternating-labels) тоже советую взглянуть.

Comment: спасибо за интересные ссылки )